# Opencv map 2D pixel coordinates to 3D world coordinates using fixed camera position

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, perspectivecamera

I am working on an autonomous vehicle project using opencv 3.0 and a raspberry pi. I am using the raspberry pi camera to do image processing for navigation. I am trying to relate pixel coordinates to 3D coordinates relative to my vehicle. The camera will be fixed on the vehicle facing forward with a known height and angle. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be extremely helpful. 
thanks!

Comment: Please post a specific example for users to go off of. We will not do the research for you.

Comment: with a single camera you can't estimate the distance of an object to the camera but you can compute the 3D position with unknown distance (= a function with possible 3D positions). If you then know one more information like the height of the object (or better said the z position of the point), you can use that information to choose one of those candidate positions.

Answer (score 0):

Image warp
[image: Image warp]

If getting the distance of the object from the car is what you are asking.
OpenCV allows Image warp. You can do a perspective transform to make the image seem as if it is being looked at from a bird's eye view.

Some calculation and calibration will be required to associate a distance with the warp values you are using. Then you'll be able to calculate the distance between the car and the object.